# How to change the color of a white bar which ovverides the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When I select a text a white bar appears and override the action bar of my application.

I tried to change the color of the copy past bar from white to orange using the following code :

```
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange_star</item>
</style>
```

but is not working.

I cannot upload an image because i have a reputation lower than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

`actionModeBackground` tag is used to change background color of Contextual actionbar.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer.

Comment: i already voted but my vote is hidden until my reputation will be greater than 15.